# Lilypond Lyrics Alignment - Align to first syllable

Tags: lilypond

Hello I am a new Lilypond user. I have a question about alignment of lyrics. Let say I have a word, with two parts (syllable) A and B. I want the syllable A align (center) to a note, but not the whole word AB. The remaining syllables B should following A, but not aligning to the next note. Is there any tweak to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{ a1 b4 c'8 b a2 a1 \bar "|." }
\addlyrics { \markup \with-dimensions-from The Theoretical "  " _ _ _ Yeah! }
```

Don't ask about the double space, though.  It's necessary so that LilyPond considers the preceding stuff center-alignable material.

But what is that supposed to be good for?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the trick and I will try this when I get back. I am entering Chinese lyrics, in which I want to center the character to the notes. But the punctuation marks (following the character) in Chinese is so big (has the same width as a character) that I need this trick.

Comment: I have installed with the latest Lilypond and it successfully compiled. Now the note a1 align with the syllable "The" which is perfect, and the remaining "oretical" follow which is perfect also. However I want the next note b4 appear after the whole word theoretical. And I do not need notes in between Theoretical and yeah also - If it is possible, please align yeah to the note b4 and make them do not overlap / clash together.